# Sortable lists in Ext JS 4

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, extjs, user-interface, sencha-architect

I'm trying to implement a sortable list in Ext JS 4. Pretty much almost exactly like the following example:

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

I'm aware that one can create a Grid Panel with a Grid Drag Drop Plugin, that approximates this. However, the difference with the jQuery UI example above is that the example has visual candy, like items shifting out of the way when you drag above them, and actually seeing the item that you are dragging (the grid drag drop plugin only shows you how many rows you are dragging).

Does something like this already exist in Ext JS? If not, what's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this custom D&D example, it might not be exactly what you want but it's a good starting point:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/dd/dragdropzones.html

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier just to use a plain `<ul>` and instantiate an [HTML5sortable](https://github.com/voidberg/html5sortable) or [rubaxa-sortable](/questions/tagged/rubaxa-sortable) on it. Rubaxa Sortable is CSS-agnostic and will play well with other libraries.

```js
new Sortable(document.getElementsByClassName('sortable')[0]);
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Sortable -->
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RubaXa/Sortable/master/Sortable.js"></script>

<ul class="list-group sortable">
  <li class="list-group-item">This is <a href="http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/">Sortable</a></li>
  <li class="list-group-item">It works with Bootstrap...</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">...out of the box.</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">It has support for touch devices.</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Just drag some elements around.</li>
</ul>
```